# Return null from procedure in MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, spring, stored-procedures, mybatis

I can't get the value back from procedure. It does an insert on a table and must return a code. The data is insert correctly, but the code returned is always null.

```
<parameterMap id="callParameters" type="Call" >
   <parameter property="client" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="originalAnalyst" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="currentAnalyst" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="analystType" jdbcType="INTEGER" mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="category" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="product" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="process" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="problem" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="priority" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="status" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="serviceType" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="abstract" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN" />
   <parameter property="descript" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="nullField" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="returnField" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="OUT"/>
   <parameter property="callNumber" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  mode="OUT" />
   <parameter property="currentDate" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" mode="IN"  />
   <parameter property="constant1" jdbcType="INTEGER" mode="IN"/>
   <parameter property="constant0" jdbcType="INTEGER" mode="IN"/>
</parameterMap>
<select id="open-call"  parameterMap="callParameters" resultType="Call"  statementType="CALLABLE">
   {call ADMAHD30.spr_AutoReq(#{returnField},#{constant1},#{callNumber},#{currentDate},#{client},#{originalAnalyst},#{currentAnalyst},#{analystType},#{category},#{product},#{process},#{problem},#{nullField},#{priority},#{status},#{serviceType},#{abstract},#{descript},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{nullField},#{constant0})}
 </select>
```

All this attributes are mappend in my object correctly. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Which is the database that you are using?

Comment: Oracle. I can't change any procedure or table. They are from another application.

Comment: `returnField` is not passed as any of the arguments to the procedure. I'm guessing one of the `nullFields` should probably be `returnField` instead?

Comment: yeah, that's right. The first parameter should be returnField, but it's still not returning the callNumber.

Comment: You try using a resultMap? I always use resultMap for databinding when I call procedures from myBatis

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on myBatis, but if you're expecting a String back, why isn't the resultType "java.lang.String"?

Edit: What about using a resultMap instead of resultType (assuming the sp has specified a name for the return params):

```
<resultMap id="CallResultMap" type="com...Call">
        <result property="callNumber" column="callNumberCol"/>
        <result property="returnField" column="returnFieldCol"/>
</resultMap>
```

and then include the result parameter in your parameterMap.

Comment: because there are 2 parameters OUT on the procedure. One of them is the code that I need.